# Check if RESTful server is available on Android

Tags: android, rest, httpurlconnection

I'm developping an Android REST-API oriented application.

I need to create a method to check whether the server is available or not.
The problem is if you use the URL.openStream() method, there's no way to determine whether a request was successful or not.

Is there a way to do it without the need to operate of performing a full HttpURLConnection and read the return code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use [TCP Sockets](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html)

   ```
   SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(address, port);
   try {
       int timeout = 2000;
       socket.connect(socketAddress, timeout);
   }
   catch (IOException e) {
         return false; 
   }
   finally {
       if (socket.isConnected()) {
           try {
               socket.close();
           }
           catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```